# What to use for Web backend development? Perl? PHP?

Tags: php, perl, user-interface, web, cgi

I'm looking to setup a pretty advanced web-based interface for a B2B application. I'm looking for a backend language to generate templates for the front end, pass the JSON data back and forth, etc.

I used to use Perl for that back in the day. However, it seems it's not as common anymore. Why is that?

If not Perl - what to use and why?

Comment: Supplanted by PHP and .NET (ASP Classic initially). Theres been somewhat of comeback with the advent of [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) and some other frameworks... If you know Perl you might want to check those out.

Comment: huge open-ended question not suitable to S.O

Comment: I didn't think it was open ended. I guess let me re-phrase: which language would you use for backend web development? OR... Why not use Perl for web development?

Comment: Perl has quite some modern and mature web frameworks: Catalyst, Mojolicious, Dancer. A lot of things have advanced since 90's CGI programming (see the [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) book for current best practices). In this day of age, it is largely irrelevant what you use: Perl, RoR or PHP. Php has a very low entry barrier: you can easily embed Php snippets in Html (but don't do that). Using a framework requires more planning ahead. Perl may not be a good choice unless you have shell access and can install modules from CPAN. Then it's pure joy :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you know Perl, the best way to use [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/), that is a mature and modern framework for developing applications.

Answer (score 1):

With the information that you have provided, I think that using [REST architectural style](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) will be the best approach for your application. You can do it in any language really, but if you are coming from a Perl background, I would recommend using PHP. I think that [Zend Framewrok 2](http://framework.zend.com/) would be a good framework for advanced web-based interface like yours. Also many find [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) helpful with its convention-over-configuration pattern, it speeds up development.

Answer (score 1):

would recomend php: WHY? because so far it is the most mature and powerful language for backendand and have a big community to support you when ever your code is  going to crash. :)